# ASP.NET Core Web Application: create model class that has default User model as property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, localdb

I have created a new project using the template for "ASP.NET Core 3.0 Web Application (Model View Controller)". It comes with authentication (register, login, logout, etc).

I now want to create a model class called InsurancePolicy that has the User property (or UserId property), obviously referencing a user in the default AspNetUsers table in my localdb.

So EFCore is code first for modelling I understand, so I have created that InsurancePolicy model class, with all the properties like Description etc. I'm following this [guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) by Microsoft.

However I don't have a model class for the AspNetUsers table in the localdb, for me to create a property on Insurance policy, e.g. `public AspNetUsers User {get; set;}`

How do I do this? Or is there a better way to do this?

I'm new to Core so code first design as opposed to db first is still blurry for me.

**UPDATE**

Looks like the model for AspNetUsers table is IdentityUser. Is this true, or am I  still lost?

Comment: Yes. By default, it's `IdentityUser`. The `AspNetUsers` table is a hold-over from the ASP.NET Membership days. Originally, Identity mimicked the same table setup from ASP.NET Membership, and it just kept following that format, even though Membership was relegated to the dustbin of history long ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example , i will add model `Book` and add a foreign key to Identity user , a book belongs to one user :

1. Create `Book.cs` :

   ```
   public class Book
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }

       public string UserId { get; set; }
       public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Modify `ApplicationDbContext` to include the DbSet:

   ```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
   {
       public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
       public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
           : base(options)
       {
       }
   }
   ```
3. `add-migration Name` and `update-database` to create table and relationship in database .
4. If you want to add a book which belongs to current user in controller  , you can firstly inject the services :

   ```
   private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
   private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
   private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
   public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
   {
       _logger = logger;
       _context = context;
       _userManager = userManager;
   }
   ```
5. Create book and save to database:

   ```
   Book book = new Book();
   //or search user by FindByIdAsync or FindByEmailAsync
   var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
   book.User = user;
   _context.Books.Add(book);
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   ```
6. If you want to read book with User properties , you can try :

   ```
   using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

   var result= _context.Books.Include(rt => rt.User).Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
   ```

Comment: I am absolutely lost on step 3 there. Where do I go to execute those steps? Are those console commands ?

Comment: Okay, looks like have to run those in package manager console.

Comment: Yes, see this :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/

Comment: Do you know how to generate the account controller? I wish to enable login from another platform, by calling the controller login method and passing to it what it needs...

Comment: [caffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Yeh, I scaffoleded those, but I only got the respective cshtml files under Areas. I have also looked at the `Login.cshtml` file, and its respective .cs file (inside it) and could not find a method I can call and pass required arguments to. No controllers where generated.

Comment: Actually, looks like there might be more to it. Let me go through that link. Cheers

Comment: It's in .cs file . for example : Login.cshtml.cs ,expend vs nodes on `Login.cshtml` to check the code file

Comment: Yes, I did that. But couldn't find an explicit `Login()` function or something close to that that I can call. Am I missing something

Comment: It will call  `OnPostAsync` to login. you might check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: For a sec I had an issue with the user property not getting populated. I just saw part 6. You are great at answering questions Nan. All details give.

Comment: How to install dotnet ef on mac: `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef` .
How to run add migration on mac: `dotnet ef migrations add migration_name` .To update database: `dotnet ef database update`